# Does the group footer scope not include detail row?

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, reportbuilder3.0

I have a Crystal report that I'm trying to convert to an SSRS report in Report Builder.  In my my Crystal Report, I have 9 groups, some with displayed headers and footers, and a couple with extra footer details that are shown conditionally.

I have my groupings, along with all headers and footers created in my SSRS report, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to hide some of my group footers, which is based on a formula field in Crystal.

In Crystal, I have 2 running total fields and a formula based on those 2 running total fields.  Each of the running total fields is just a count that resets on a group change.  The formula is a mod of the first against the second, along with some other conditions.  Based on the formula, a group footer is hidden or not.

In Report Builder, group 6 has the first running total (Group variable `inv_count`), group 8 has the second running total (Group variable `group_count`).  In the detail section, I've made the Group varialbe (for testing, just inv_count - group_count) called `mod`.

When I put a textbox with `mod` in one of the footers for group 6 and run the report, I get the following error:  `The Value expression for the text box ‘Textbox169’ refers to the Variable ‘mod’. Expressions can only refer to a Variable declared within the same grouping scope, a containing grouping scope, or those declared on the report.`
Is the footer not included in the group scope, or is the detail not included in the scope for a footer?

This is probably the most complicated report we have, but if we can't port it, it's a deal breaker.

Thank you for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

Just to reassure you, Report Builder should be capable of handling all your report conversions. We did the same thing at my last job converted all of them.

I would steer away from using group variables. Honestly, I have never used them. The important thing to understand is the scope of an expression. For example, if you just put:

```
=Sum(Fields!inv_count.Value - Fields!group_count.Value)
```

This will give you the total at the current scope. So it is naturally filtered based on whichever groups it falls within. You can also override the scope like this:

```
=Sum(Fields!inv_count.Value - Fields!group_count.Value, "group8")
```

Now you get a total across that specific group. You can also use both expression together to compare them. These are essentially the same thing as a group variable. Where you run into trouble is if you try to override the scope to a group that's not available.

I think that's the best answer I can give without knowing more specifics about the report layout and data structure. This is general advice that should point you in the right direction.

Comment: I assume `just` is a typo in the `Sum()`?  Are you suggesting that variables aren't the best way to keep track of 'things', or are there other kinds of variables?

Comment: Yeah, "just" was a copy and paste mistake. I'm suggesting that you use the native grouping capabilities to aggregate data in the report.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm confused; you say don't use variables, then as an example you show using variables.

Comment: I updated the syntax for you. The point is that SSRS has native grouping capabilities to handle aggregation. As you learn how grouping and scope work, it will help you recreate your reports.

Answer (score -1):

The group footer scope contains the details row, but the details row's scope does not contain a footer row of an outer group.

The "details section" is the innermost group of the report. A variable defined in that group can only be accessed there. If you want to use a variable in a specific group, that variable has to be defined in that group or in a group further out (or at the report level, which is the outermost scope). The scope of a group variable is that group and the inner groups down to the retails row.

**Example (added):**

Imagine a list of *products* that appear on *orders* that are submitted by *customers*. On the *product* level, you can tell the name of the *customer*, but on the *customer* level, you can't tell "the name of **the** *product*" (because *customers* submit multiple *orders* that contain multiple *products*).

Comment: Was there something wrong with my answer? Would that someone who downvoted please explain? Downvoting correct answers won't help the community, because the authors might remove them.